# Copy rows from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create a master sheet for our managers that only include activity happening in their areas (I have a script for this that does what I need). These sheets are populated from my master sheet (and are not in the same workbook).

I need to have rows copy to the applicable sheet when there is a new submission. My code below dumps them all to one sheet and I'm not sure why. I'm assuming I don't have the right condition but how do you say "move rows to this sheet when it's this manager"? I thought calling the sheet ID by row would be enough, but I guess not.

Would I then have to do an if else statement for every manager? That will get tedious since I have about 80 managers.

Below is my current code. Any help or advice is appreciated!

```
function moveRows(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

    // Grab the Headers
  var headers = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var nameCol = headers[0].indexOf('Enter Your Name');
  var candCol = headers[0].indexOf('Choose Candidate');
  var typeCol = headers[0].indexOf('Merged Experience');
  var docCol = headers[0].indexOf('Document Link');
  var timeCol = headers[0].indexOf('Timestamp');
  var subjectCol = headers[0].indexOf('Choose the Content Area');
  var ratingsCol = headers[0].indexOf('Ratings Summary');
  var accessCol = headers[0].indexOf('Access');
  var activityCol = headers[0].indexOf('Copied to Activity Sheet');
  var masterCol = headers[0].indexOf('Master Activity Sheet');
  var target = [];

  // Loop over the values line by line
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = data[i];
  var name = row[nameCol];
  var activity = row[activityCol];
  var master = row[masterCol];
  var candidate = row[candCol];
  var type = row[typeCol];
  var subject = row[subjectCol];
  var ratings = row[ratingsCol];
  var access = row[accessCol];
  var guide = row[docCol];
  var time = row[timeCol];

  if (activity == "") { // if condition is true copy the whole row to target
   target.push([time,name,candidate,subject,type,guide,ratings]);
   Logger.log(target);


  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(master);
    var sh2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
        sh2.getDataRange().offset(sh2.getLastRow(), 0, target.length, target[0].length).setValues(target);
  } 
 }
}
```

**Note:** I have a bunch of different scripts that move rows from one tab to another, but I couldn't find anything where I move it across multiple workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have an array with for each manager the sheet where to copy the data.

```
var managerSheet = {
"manager1":"SheetAzerty",
"manager2":"SheetQwerty"
};
```

to select the sheet just do :

```
var manager = "manager1"; //This is the value you retrieve

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(managerSheet[manager]);
```

Stéphane

Comment: Thanks for responding! Does it matter that they are in different workbooks? To me it looks like the code is saying get the active sheet and select tab "manager 1". Am I reading that incorrectly?